# How to multiply DataFrame in 'pandas'?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two probability table p(B) and p(A|B):

```
pB_array=np.array([[0.97],[0.01],[0.02]])
pB = pd.DataFrame(pB_array,index=['B=n','B=m','B=s'])
pA_B_array=np.array([[0.9,0.8,0.3],[0.1,0.2,0.7]])
pA_B=pd.DataFrame(pA_B_array,index=['A=F','A=T'],columns=['B=n','B=m','B=s'])
```

I want to multiply them by columns:

```
fAB=pA_B.multiply(pB.T,axis='columns')
```

And get some result like:

```
     B=n  B=m  B=s
A=F  0.1  0.2  0.3
A=T  0.5  0.4  0.1
```

But I can only get this:

```
     B=n  B=m  B=s
0    NaN  NaN  NaN
A=F  NaN  NaN  NaN
A=T  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

How could I make it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is alignment will occur along the axes, as these don't match you get `NaN` values.

```
In [173]:

fAB=pA_B.multiply(pB.T.squeeze().values,axis='columns')
fAB
Out[173]:
       B=n    B=m    B=s
A=F  0.873  0.008  0.006
A=T  0.097  0.002  0.014
```

We need to call `squeeze` here as the shape is wrong if this not done, also we can anonymise the data by calling `.values` to return a np array so that the alignment doesn't become an issue.

```
fAB=pA_B.multiply(pB.T.values,axis='columns')
```

results in:

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 1), indices imply (3, 2)

As:

```
In [176]:

print(pB.T.shape)
print(pB.T.squeeze().shape)
(1, 3)
(3,)
```

So [`squeeze`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.squeeze.html?highlight=squeeze#pandas.DataFrame.squeeze) flattens the 2-d array to a 1-d array